# How Capture image using camera 'Circle' overlay and Save it on path in Xamarin.forms (Android)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, camera-overlay

I am new in xamarin.forms and i wants to make a app using **xamarin.forms** for capture a image and save in given path. i also want add **Camera Overlay** to crop image in **Circle** shape. I have found below sample project-

'https://github.com/CrossGeeks/OverlaySample'

and modified it to add button in common project and call capture event using rendering. capture event successfully fire but image capturing not working because of 'SurfaceView' in above sample.

Please help- How to capture image using **'SurfaceView'**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Answer (score 0):

`SurfaceView` is in used in the native Android, you could create a customview that include an surfaceview in android project,then create a custom viewrenderer and `SetNativeControl(your customview)` your could refer to the `CameraPreviewRenderer` ,`NativeCameraPreview` classes in android project and `CameraPreview` class in forms project.You can refer to [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) for more information and a [sample](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/surfaceview/android-surfaceview-example/) for using surfaceview