# Xamarin.forms open camera inside popup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way we can open camera in a custom popup in xamarin.forms? Currently I am using `Xam.Plugin.Media` which will open camera in an entire screen. what I am trying to mimic is open the camera inside a circular frame to show inside `Rg.Plugin.Popup` . How can I achieve it? Does it require platform level implementation? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I find a [feature-request - Cropping interface](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/214) of `Xam.Plugin.Media` and the author refused it `as it should be done in a different app since it is not available out of the box on all platforms`.

You can have a try with [Take Photo Overlay (iOS Only)](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#take-photo-overlay-ios-only) function of this plugin to add a layer in iOS camera.

I also find a useful [OverlaySample](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/OverlaySample) of Xamarin.forms which can add overlayer to camera in Xamarin.forms.

Refer: [overlayview-in-xamarin-forms](http://www.xamboy.com/2019/02/23/overlayview-in-xamarin-forms/)

[how-capture-image-using-camera-circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004855/how-capture-image-using-camera-circle-overlay-and-save-it-on-path-in-xamarin-f)

Comment: Hi bro Thanks . Will the overlay sample will help me to achieve this in crosplatform way?

Comment: You can have a try as there is a overlayerView on camera sample there. I think it almost meet your requirement.

Comment: Let me check bro.

Comment: Bro it worked. Thanks  Can you help me on this part? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908778/xamarin-forms-ios-take-image-using-camera-natively?noredirect=1#comment113011412_63908778